# Batch job failing - System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out

Tags: c#

```
    public void UploadToFTP(string sourceFile, string ftpFolderPath)
    {
        var fileInf = new FileInfo(sourceFile);
        var ftpPathSb = string.Format("ftp://{0}/{1}/{2}", _ftpInfo[Constants.FTPVariables.N_COL_FTP_KEY_HOST],
            ftpFolderPath, fileInf.Name);
        //create an ftp request
        var reqFtp = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(new Uri(ftpPathSb));
        reqFtp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        reqFtp.Proxy = null;
        reqFtp.KeepAlive = false;
        reqFtp.UseBinary = true;
        reqFtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_ftpInfo[Constants.FTPVariables.N_COL_FTP_KEY_ID],
            _ftpInfo[Constants.FTPVariables.N_COL_FTP_KEY_PW]);
        reqFtp.ContentLength = fileInf.Length;
        const int buffLength = 2048;
        var buff = new byte[buffLength];
        var fs = fileInf.OpenRead();
        try
        {
            // Stream to which the file to be upload is written
            var strm = reqFtp.GetRequestStream();

            // Read from the file stream 2kb at a time
            var contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);

            // Till Stream content ends
            while (contentLen != 0)
            {
                // Write Content from the file stream to the
                // FTP Upload Stream
                strm.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
                contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
            }

            // Close the file stream and the Request Stream
            strm.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
```

> Error Details :Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out.
>      at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.CheckError()
>      at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at NorthernTrust.DSE.Core.Services.Ftp.Ftp.DownloadFromFTP(String fileName, String ftpFolderPath)
>      at NorthernTrust.DSE.Core.Business.Controllers.FtpController.DownloadFromFTP(String fileName, String ftpFolderPath)
>      at NorthernTrust.DSE.DSEBatch.Console.Program.Main()
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
>      at NorthernTrust.DSE.Core.Services.Ftp.Ftp.UploadToFTP(String sourceFile, String ftpFolderPath)
>      at NorthernTrust.DSE.Core.Business.Controllers.FtpController.UploadToFTP(String sourceFile, String ftpFolderPath)
>      at NorthernTrust.DSE.DSEBatch.Console.Program.LogMove(String fName)
>      at NorthernTrust.DSE.DSEBatch.Console.Program.Main()

Comment: Batch job is failing due to this Timeout error. How can i avoid this or make it re-Run the job again. Thanks

Comment: If you do not even put forth the minimal effort to make the code in your post readable, it is unlikely that people will try very hard to help you.

Comment: @ Joe: I am sorry. I tried but i couldn't do it. Tried again and its better now. Kindly advice on this. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like your code cannot connect to the FTP server for some reason.  I would try to get a dump of exactly what string is in ftpPathSb at runtime, and then try to connect to that same address with a normal FTP client.  This will tell you if maybe ftpPathSb is no longer correct because the FTP server's address changed or something.

Comment: This runs at every weekend.Once the job is failing we are re-running it and it executes successfully second time.